# I have a data frame with Few columns and want sum of rows of a specific column with +1 row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

Input DF:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 24 |
| BB | 37 |
| CC | 59 |

Desired Output Dataframe:

| Column A | Column B | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 24 | 24 |
| BB | 37 | 61 |
| CC | 59 | 120 |

What I want is result column should have 24 in first row,
24+37 in 2nd row ,24+37+59 in 3rd row and so on.
Kindly help

I am a beginner and was trying to solve this problem by using sum

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) :

```
df["Column C"]= df["Column B"].cumsum()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
​
  Column A  Column B  Column C
0       AA        24        24
1       BB        37        61
2       CC        59       120
```